# Husky model in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, clearpath, husky, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the Clearpath Husky model in Gazebo.  The URDF and launch files are working fine and I can spawn the model, but it is crushing my high end system.  Just got off the phone with Clearpath and they are aware of the excessive fidelity of their model and looking into simplifying.

Just looking for a comparison, what kind of "% of real time" and FPS are people seeing when spawning this model in empty_world?  I am getting about 0.6-0.7 but only 1 or 2 fps.  Running Ubuntu 11.10 w/electric, 16GB mem, SSD, GTX670 w/xconfig, ivy bridge i7.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45935/husky-model-in-gazebo/) by [dabigshue](https://answers.ros.org/users/3390/dabigshue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-10-15**:
Odd. Checking on my end, I'm getting 0.5x real time, 20 fps. Configured for 11.10/electric, 32 GB RAM, i7-2760QM (Sandy Bridge), nVidia Quadro 2000M set to be always-on (Optimus). By all rights, your machine should shatter my numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone who is interested, this has been improved (currently in [our stack](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/husky_simulator) on github, en-route to the builds). I am seeing a 300% real-time number with a Husky in an empty world on my machine.

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1